# How to remove first and last double quotation marks and backslash of JSON Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to remove first and last double quotation marks and backslash of a JSON data in javascript

"{\"documents\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"language\":\"en\",\"text\":\"I had a wonderful trip to Seattle last week and even visited the Space Needle 2 times!\"}]}"

I expect the output is:

{"documents":[{"id":"1","language":"en","text":"I had a wonderful trip to Seattle last week and even visited the Space Needle 2 times!"}]}"

Comment: Where do you see those backslashes and quotes? Because this looks like what you might get in a *console* - if so, this is merely the representation of the data, and there are no first and last quote nor backslashes in the real data.

Comment: That's a string--did you try `JSON.parse` to convert it to an object?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the first and last characters you can use `str.substr(1, str.length-2);`